# How to find edge of div for touchscreen swipe div?

Tags: javascript, events, touch, swipe, mousemove

I now have a working touchscreen image slider but the only problem is that when I touchscreen the movement position begins from the center of the div and moves the whole div to be positioned with the pointer in the middle and lift off screen - and then attempt to do another movement. the movement position begins again in the center of the div.

I know I need to reset the co-ords somehow when I lift off screen, or maybe unbind, but I have no idea how to do this. It takes me days if not weeks to simply figure these things out without help. Don't get me wrong I'm all about learning for myself, but I also learn a great deal more where I can examine a working solution of my own code.

Here is a little HTML for the divs:

```
    .container{
      position:absolute;
      top:0%;
      left:0%;
      width:500px;
      height:100%;
    }

    .drag{
      position: absolute;
      top:1%; 
      left:0%;
      width:100%;
      height:15%;
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
      border-style: solid; 2px;
      border-color: blue;
      z-index:1000;
    }

    </head>

    <body>

<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id='drag' class='drag'><!---video area--->

  some images

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the swipe events.

```
var dom = {
    container: document.getElementById("container"),
    drag: document.getElementById("drag"),
}
var container = {
    x: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().left,
    y: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().top,
    w: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().width,
    h: dom.container.getBoundingClientRect().height
}
var drag = {
    w: dom.drag.offsetWidth 
}

target = null;

document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', handleTouchEnd, false);
document.body.addEventListener('touchcancel', handleTouchCancel, false);

function handleTouchStart(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 1) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        target = touch.target;
    }
}
function handleTouchMove(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 1) {
        if(target ===  dom.drag) {
            moveDrag(e);
        }
    }
}
function handleTouchEnd(e) {
    if (e.touches.length == 0) { // User just took last finger off screen
        target = null;
    }
}
function handleTouchCancel(e) {
    return;
}

function moveDrag(e) {
    var touch = e.touches[0];
    var posX = touch.pageX - container.x - drag.w / 2;


    dom.drag.style.left = posX + "px";

    }
```

I KNOW IT'S DOWN TO THIS LINE OF CODE:

```
var posX = touch.pageX - container.x - drag.w / 2;
```

HERE IS THE FIDDLE:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/xbmyazb2/20/
```

Comment: Hi Russ. I am at a loss why you've thrown my improvements/edits away, so I will restore them. The original was hard to read because several files, and their introductions, had been shown in one code block. If it is important to you to have the post as you originally wrote it, would you ping me first at `@halfer` so we can discuss? Thanks!

Comment: Also, please read: [Why can people edit my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: trying to delete the posts as they where a little messed up ect... v.sorry